# Need a better way to find repeated words in a string

Tags: java

I need a way to do the same operation with much less code. This will help me to understand Java in much better way.
OUTPUT of the below code will be:
new, boy, 3pm, to

```
public class substring {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String str= "a new, boy with new haircut boy, 3pm to boy 8pm margian 3pm to ghost";
    String concant = "";
    int occurance =0;
    str = str.replaceAll(",", "");
    System.out.println(str);
    String[] subStr = str.split("\\s");
    for(String sub:subStr)
    {
        for (String sub1:subStr) {
            if(sub.equals(sub1))
            { 
                 occurance++;
                    
                if(occurance>=2)
                {
                    if(!concant.contains(sub))
                    {
                        if(concant!= "")
                          concant = concant +", "+ sub;
                        else
                            concant = sub;
                              
                    }
                }
            }
            
        }   
        occurance = 0;  
    }
    System.out.println(concant);
    
}

}
```

Comment: You can use `hashing` for efficient checking. Loop through all the words and check if the word is present, if its not add it to the hashtable else add it to am empty string.

Comment: We can use hashmap. However, in the output there is only words and not their frequency, so hashset should work too.

Comment: It won't give you all words with a frequency of 2 or more, looks like that's what the code is doing.

Comment: *Need a better way to find repeated words in a string*  Then forget about frequency counts and use `HashSets`.

Answer (score 6):

## Solution

Instead of using nested loops you can take advantage of the functionality provided by a set data structure.  A set is a collection that cannot contain duplicates.  So by checking the truthiness of the add method you can determine duplicates

```
String[] listContainingDuplicates = "a new, boy with new haircut boy, 3pm to boy 8pm margian 3pm to ghost".split("[,\\s]+");
    
final LinkedHashSet<String> duplicates = new LinkedHashSet<String>(); 
final Set<String> temp = new HashSet<>();
    
for ( final String current : listContainingDuplicates ){
    if ( !temp.add( current ) )
        duplicates.add( current );
}
    
System.out.println( duplicates.toString() );
```

> Treat this as pseudo code.  There may be edge cases that you want to handle

Your solution has a time complexity of O(N^2) while the solution provided above runs in O(n)

Comment: Try it with a similar string as shown in the question.  `the new dog, dog new`

Comment: If it's important to keep the order of duplicate words, `LinkedHashSet` should be used for `duplicates`  Also, non-word characters (e.g. commas) should be removed or treated as delimiters.

Comment: @NikolaiDmitriev  It doesn't miss the point.  The question asks for a better method.  And this is it (once the string is correctly split).

Comment: Thanks for feedback.  I added a regex to better meet requirements, and used a LinkedHashSet.  It is my opinion that this answer meets the requirements outlined by Suvidh and at least serves as counter to @m.antkowicz functional solution

Answer (score 2):

Just split by spaces and group using streams, tthen filter these having less occurrences than two

```
String str= "a new, boy with new haircut boy, 3pm to boy 8pm margian 3pm to ghost";
str = str.replaceAll(",", "");

List<String> duplicates = Arrays.stream(str.split(" "))
    .filter(s -> !s.isEmpty())
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()))
    .entrySet()
    .stream()
    .filter(e -> e.getValue() > 1)
    .map(e -> e.getKey())
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: you nailed it, respect

Comment: It's unnecessary to "delete" the commas.  Just use this. `List<String> duplicates = Arrays.stream(str.split("[,\\s]+"))`

Comment: Thaks all this is useful.